# FEM: how to find 2D flow under external forcing?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method

I'm trying to sovle a 2D Navier-Stokes equation in a rectangular region with no-flow boundary conditions and an external rotating force $f(x,y)=(-y,x)$. I've got the error message:

> NDSolveValue::index: The DAE solver failed at t = 0.. The solver is intended for index 1 DAE systems and structural analysis indicates that the DAE index is 2. The option Method->{"IndexReduction"->Automatic} may be used to reduce the index of the system.

I don't see why it does not work. It very similar to the tutorial examples. Could you, please, help me to solve this problem?

This is my code:

````
Ω = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];

op = 
  {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
     Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
     {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]} . 
        Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
     Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][t, x, y] - y, 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] + 
     Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
     {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]} . 
        Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
      Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][t, x, y] + x, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, y] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][t, x, y]};

bcs = 
  {DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, True], 
   DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == -1 && y == -1]};

ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};

Monitor[
  AbsoluteTiming[
    {xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
      NDSolveValue[
        {op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs, ic}, {u, v, p}, {x, y} ∈ Ω, {t, 0, 1},
        Method -> 
          {"PDEDiscretization" -> 
            {"MethodOfLines",
             "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
               {"FiniteElement", 
                "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}, 
                "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
        EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];], 
  currentTime]
```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solver works well at low acceleration, so we need to multiply the force by a damping factor $f=(-y,x)(1-e^{-t})$, then we have a solution

```
Ω = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];

op = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
    Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
      y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
      u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][t, x, y] - 
    y (1 - Exp[-t]), 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] + 
    Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
      y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][t, x, y] + 
    x (1 - Exp[-t]), 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, y] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][t, x, y]};

bcs = {DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, True], 
   DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == -1 && y == -1]};

ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};

Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
    NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs, ic}, {u, v, 
      p}, {x, y} ∈ Ω, {t, 0, 10}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}, 
           "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = 
        Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];], currentTime]

Table[StreamDensityPlot[
  Evaluate[{xVel[t, x, y], yVel[t, x, y]}], {x, 
    y} ∈ Ω, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, 1, 10, 3}]
```

[image: Figure 1]
Update 1. Numerical solution looks quite different with periodic boundary condition on `x`:

```
bcsp = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[

t, x, y], x == -1 && -1 < y < 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{2, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == -1 && -1 < y < 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{2, 0}]], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, 
     v[t, x, y] == 0}, (y == -1 || y == 1) && -1 < x < 1], 
   DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == -1 && y == -1]};
Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[{xVel1, yVel1, pressure1} = 
    NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcsp, ic}, {u, v, 
      p}, {x, y} ∈ Ω, {t, 0, 10}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}, 
           "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = 
        Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];], currentTime]
Table[StreamDensityPlot[
  Evaluate[{xVel1[t, x, y], yVel1[t, x, y]}], {x, 
    y} ∈ Ω, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic], {t, 1, 4, 1}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

To simulate Poiseuille flow in a flat channel driven by force $F_x=t$  we put $p=const$ and remove continuity equation from a system, finally we have

```
op1 = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
    Inactive[Div][-I

nactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
      y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
      u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - t, 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] + 
    Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
      y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y], {x, y}]};

ic1 = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0};
bcsp1 = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], x == -1 && -1 < y < 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{2, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == -1 && -1 < y < 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{2, 0}]], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, 
     v[t, x, y] == 0}, (y == -1 || y == 1) && -1 < x < 1]};
Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[{xVel1, yVel1} = 
    NDSolveValue[{op1 == {0, 0}, bcsp1, ic1}, {u, 
      v}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, 2}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}, 
           "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2}}}}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = 
        Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];], currentTime]
```

Visualisation

```
{Table[DensityPlot[
   Evaluate[xVel1[t, x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic], {t, .2, 2, .3}], 
 Plot[Table[xVel1[t, 0, y], {t, .2, 2, .3}], {y, -1, 1}]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: may be you also know how to adjust  **PeriodicBoundaryCondition**? Solver stucks after a few steps.   `bcs = {
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], x == -1 && -1 <= y <= 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{2, 0}]],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == -1 && -1 <= y <= 1, 
    TranslationTransform[{2, 0}]],
   DirichletCondition[
    u[t, x, y] == 0, (y == -1 || y == 1) && -1 < x <= 1],
   DirichletCondition[
    v[t, x, y] == 0, (y == -1 || y == 1) && -1 < x <= 1],
   DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == -1 && y == -1]};`

Comment: @RodionStepanov Yes, I know, see update to my answer.

Comment: Unfortumatly, channel flow does not appear because of the pressure is still not periodic. Can you get correct channel flow solving equastions with external force `Fx=t` and `Fy=0`?

Comment: @RodionStepanov There is no periodic boundary condition for pressure in your conditions. So what kind of channel flow you suppose to simulate?

Comment: for pressue there is neither a solid wall boundary condition. I look for plane Poiseuille flow between two parallel plates and extrenal force in horizonatal direction. Non-slip condition for velocity at top and bottom. Periodic velocity in x-coordinate.  It should give the preriodic pressure automatically.

Comment: @RodionStepanov Do you try to solve NSE with the initial condition `ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};` and get Poiseuille flow?

Comment: yes, these initial condition + external forcing  `Fx=t, Fx=0`. Flow will not be stationary but profile shound be parabolic.

Comment: @RodionStepanov There are no unique solution with this force, since $p=tx, u=0,v=0$ is  a solution too. So FEM gets this solution first.

Comment: you are right. How can I get nontrivial periodic solution for _u_ and _v_?

Comment: @RodionStepanov See update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need pressure. What to do for such region `\[CapitalOmega] = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
   Rectangle[{-1/2, -1}, {1/2, -1/2}]];`?

Comment: @RodionStepanov If you need pressure then there is no Poiseuille flow, and there is no unique solution with periodic boundary condition. I recommend you to start new post about flow in the region $\Omega$.